Derivation at a point for mappings differentiable at that point
I'm reading Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", and I'm trying to understeand which definitions and proofs do not really require $C^\infty$-ness, but only weaker conditions, like $C^k$ ness for some $k$, or even less.
When the author discusses the isomorphism from the set of geometric vectors $\mathbb{R}^n_a$, to the set of derivations at the point $a$, $T_a\mathbb{R}^n$ (proposition 3.2), he does so by considering derivations as linear functionals satisfying Liebnitz rule on the space $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (however following the reasoning given by the author it is evident how weaker smoothness conditions are sufficient).
My question is then, if we consider the set of derivations at the point $a$, to be the set of linear functionals on the set of mappings that are differentiable at $a$, satisfying Liebnitz rule, do we get the same result?

No. You get an infinite-dimensional space. This has been discussed on this site in the past.

Oh, that's sad. Can you link the old discussion? I didn't manage to find it. Also, do you know what may be softer smoothness conditions? Like differentiability a.e. or Lipschitz condition? Tank you for you answer by the way.

For $C^k$ with $k<\infty$ the result still fails! See this post for a somewhat thorough discussion.
